# How to get rid of tile outlines when tiling textures to a mesh?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm creating a sphere and attaching images to each face of the sphere. In my code I have sphere 12 sections by 6 sections high. I've managed to tile the textures by setting the wrap to repeating and setting the repeat size like so:

```
var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( path );

texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( geo_width, geo_height );                

return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.BackSide, overdraw: true  });
```

It works but now I have these lines between each texture. Is there a way to get rid of them or is there another technique for face-tiling that I should be using?

[image: Outlines on textures]

Answer (score 0):

The lines are the opposite edge of each texture tile appearing at the edges of the geometry. This is what repeating textures do, which is not appropriate in this case.

You don't say what happens when you don't use repeating, but it sounds like what you need to do is adjust the *texture coordinate* generation so that the coordinates are 0...1 on *each tile* rather than only on the “0th tile” of the entire sphere.

I don't know Three.js so I can't advise you specifically on its API, sorry.

Comment: Without repeating, Three.js defaults it to gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE which causes each texture to wrap around the entire sphere but only show within each tile. So every tile texture looks very very pixelated.

Comment: @dcap So you need to adjust the _texture coordinates_ of the sphere tiles to scale/translate the texture appropriately.